# How to physically create 10 workstations that all run on virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization

I heard of a company that saves electricity by having all of their workstations run on virtual machines. So instead of 11 computers (10 workstations and a server), they only have the server which hosts all the workstations as virtual machines.

But how does this physically work? How do the monitor, keyboard, and mouse "use" the virtual machine without a host machine? Is there some kind of very cheap hardware one can buy which the monitor, keyboard and mouse connect to, then that hardware connects to the server via WIFI, or how would this work?

Comment: YOu still require the thin client which require power granted a lot less but still needed, it works by delivering the desktop to the user over the network and the end user sees the computer boot up like normal but its booting from the server and the server deal with all the command for mouse monitor etc

Answer (score 2):

I think what you refer to would be an implementation of what some call [Thin Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) technology.

This usually requires a decent server and cheap hardware a.k.a. "dumb" terminal workstations, which simply connect to your server and display what is essentially a virtual machine, sometimes just within a browser.  The server is actually running the software and doing the grunt work, although the average user may not be aware given the user experience can 
resemble logging into a regular networked computer.

If you are considering implementing this type of infrastructure, it has been around for some time, so be sure to read and learn from the experiences and advice of others.  I don't think it generally matters if you want to go with wired or wireless connections (I have seen networks using both), but I suspect those more learned might make various arguments for wired.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technology called NX Server. It is client-server. You can afford you not a virtual machines but real evironment with Graphical User Interface (with mouse and keyboard) working separately for every connected client. If you run Linux on your server you will find a free software called [FreeNX, here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) is the documentation from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something called NComputing, which was used at the startup I had earlier worked for. You have a server on which the NComputing card and software is installed. The workstations consist of a monitor, keyboard and a mouse. If I am not wrong, the workstations were connected to the server via ordinary LAN cables.

There is a limit on the physical distance between the server and the workstations. The number of workstations is dependant on the capacity of the NComputing card.

One of the irritating side effects was that the monitors on the workstations almost always used to be dimmer than "ordinary" computers monitors.